# Macro or VB to clean up data after CSV import to ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

Currently, I am pulling 1 csv file daily then running it through an excel macro to clean my data. Once clean, I import it to my table in ms access (i only have 1 table in the db).

The csv data has 7 columns ... tracking number (;and portcode), followed by package info and time stamp.

ColA must only contain tracking number, and colB the portcode. Problem is that the data file has rows where the portcode comes before tracking number. Here is where my macro comes in handy to split and put the right data in the right column.

```
Data sample: <br>
<h1>colA<h1/><br>
TN123456789;3-CTC-A1T <br>
TN987654321;3-TPO-B2 <br>
TN111122222;N-BKK-A1 <br>
N-BKK-B1;TN222211111 <br>
S-KKC-C1T;TN33333333

Result:<br>
<h1>colA<h1/><br>
TN123456789<br>
TN987654321<br>
TN111122222<br>
TN222211111<br>
TN33333333<br>

<h1>colB<h1/><br>
3-CTC-A1T<br>
3-TPO-B2<br>
N-BKK-A1<br>
N-BKK-B1<br>
S-KKC-C1T<br>
```

Question(s):
Rather than going through excel for clean-up then access for import, is it possible to import the csv data file, then let access clean my data for me before appending it to my table?
If yes, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

here my +1 solution;
- Read file
- Clean file into memory
- Output file with ready to import data

```
Sub demo_cleanbuffer()
'
'=======================================================================================
' Procedure : demo_cleanbuffer (Sub)
' Module    : Module1 (Module)
' Project   : VBAProject
' Author    : misterneo
' Date      : 12/02/2016
' Comments  : **MANDATORY**
' Unit Test : 12/02/2016 10:10 | Description [OK]
' Arg./i    :
'           - [NO PARAM]
'           -
'           -
' Arg./o    : ()
'
'Changes--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Date               Programmer                      Change
'12/02/2016         GRT / GAZ               Initiate
'
'=======================================================================================
'

Dim filen As Byte
Dim arrStr() As Variant
Dim arrReturn() As String
Dim buffer As String

'Note : String to erase
arrStr = Array("<br>", "<h1>", "<h1/>", "colA")
'Note : read file

Open "C:\tmp.txt" For Binary Access Read As #1
    buffer = Space(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , buffer
Close #1

'Note : erase unwanted string
For i = LBound(arrStr) To UBound(arrStr)
    buffer = Replace(buffer, arrStr(i), "")
Next i

'Note : store each buffer line into array
arrReturn = Split(buffer, vbCrLf)

'Note : write data into text file
Open "C:\tmpo.txt" For Output As #1
    For i = LBound(arrReturn) To UBound(arrReturn)
        If Not Len(arrReturn(i)) = 0 Then Print #1, Trim(arrReturn(i))
    Next i
Close #1

End Sub
```